# IIS & service-based generation of web images - GDI, GDI+ or Direct2D?

Tags: c#, gdi+, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

It is May 2017. My boss has asked me to produce some code to make some custom web images on our website based on text that the user enters into their browser.

The Server environment is Windows 2012 running IIS, and I am familiar with C#. From what I read I should be able to use GDI+ to create images, draw smooth text into them etc.

However, one of my colleagues suggested GDI+ may not work on Windows Server, and that GDI+ is based on older GDI which is 32-bit and will therefore be scrapped one day soon, and that I should use DirectX instead. I feel that to introduce another layer would make matters more complex to write & support.

There are a lot of web pages discussing these subjects as well as performance of each but it feels inconclusive so I ask for experience from the SO community.

So, question: Will GDI work on Windows Server ?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. I see from them that I was a tad vague on a couple of points. Specifically, we are intending the rendering to image process to be a queue-based process with a service running the GDI+ graphics code. I have just read [this from 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/16/using-direct2d-from-a-service-in-c/) which suggests that GDI+ should not be run within a service, and suggesting that Direct2D is the MS preferred way-to-go.

EDIT 2: Further research has found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485857(v=vs.85).aspx). It says the options are GDI, GDI+ or Direct2D. I copy the key paras here, though the entire page is a quick read so view at source for context if you can.

> **Options for Available APIs**
>
> There are three options for server-side rendering: GDI, GDI+ and
>   Direct2D. Like GDI and GDI+, Direct2D is a native 2D rendering API
>   that gives applications more control over the use of graphics devices.
>   In addition, Direct2D uniquely supports a single-threaded and a
>   multithreaded factory. The following sections compare each API in
>   terms of drawing qualities and multithreaded server-side rendering.
>
> **GDI**
>
> Unlike Direct2D and GDI+, GDI does not support high-quality
>   drawing features. For instance, GDI does not support antialiasing for
>   creating smooth lines and has only limited support for transparency.
>   Based on the graphics performance test results on Windows 7 and
>   Windows Server 2008 R2, Direct2D scales more efficiently than GDI,
>   despite the redesign of locks in GDI. For more information about these
>   test results, see Engineering Windows 7 Graphics Performance. In
>   addition, applications using GDI are limited to 10240 GDI handles per
>   process and 65536 GDI handles per session. The reason is that
>   internally Windows uses a 16-bit WORD to store the index of handles
>   for each session.
>
> **GDI+***
>
> While GDI+ supports antialiasing and alpha
>   blending for high-quality drawing, the main problem with GDI+ for
>   server-scenarios is that it does not support running in Session 0.
>   Since Session 0 only supports non-interactive functionality, functions
>   that directly or indirectly interact with display devices will
>   therefore receive errors. Specific examples of functions include not
>   only those dealing with display devices, but also those indirectly
>   dealing with device drivers. Similar to GDI, GDI+ is limited by its
>   locking mechanism. The locking mechanisms in GDI+ are the same in
>   Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 as in previous versions.
>
> **Direct2D**
>
> Direct2D is a hardware-accelerated, immediate-mode, 2-D graphics API
>   that provides high performance and high-quality rendering. It offers a
>   single-threaded and a multithreaded factory and the linear scaling of
>   course-grained software rendering. To do this, Direct2D defines a root
>   factory interface. As a rule, an object created on a factory can only
>   be used with other objects created from the same factory. The caller
>   can request either a single-threaded or a multithreaded factory when
>   it is created. If a single-threaded factory is requested, then no
>   locking of threads is performed. If the caller requests a
>   multithreaded factory, then, a factory-wide thread lock is acquired
>   whenever a call is made into Direct2D. In addition, the locking of
>   threads in Direct2D is more granular than in GDI and GDI+, so that the
>   increase of the number of threads has minimal impact on the
>   performance.

After some discussion of threading and some sample code, it concludes...

> **Conclusion**
>
> As seen from the above, using Direct2D for server-side rendering is simple and straightforward. In addition, it provides high quality and highly parallelizable rendering that can run in low-privilege environments of the server.

Whilst I interpret the slant of the piece as being pro-Direct2D, the points on locking and session-0 for GDI+ are concerning. Arguably, since we propose a queue-based process, the locking issue is less severe, but if there are immediate and practical restrictions to what a service can do with GDI+ then it looks like Direct2D is the only viable route for my project.

Did I interpret this correctly or has the SO community more recent & relevant experience?

EDIT: With the initial batch of responses slowing up and no sign of a definitive answer, I add this edit. The team here has selected [sharpdx](http://sharpdx.org/) as a wrapping library to MS DirectWrite which is itself part of the Direct3D family of API's. We are not 100% certain that sharpdx will be required and we will be comparing it to a solely DirectWrite implementation as we go along looking out for the benefit or hindrance the extra layer represents. We believe at this point in time that this follows the direction MS were trying to suggest in the article sampled above, and that we will be free of GDI/+ shortcomings in a service environment and able to benefit from performance and feature gains in DirectWrite. We shall see.

EDIT: Having delved into SharpDx we are making progress and something mentioned by Mgetz about 'WARP' now makes sense. Direct3D is the underpinning tech we access via the SharpDX API. AS with all low-level graphics work, we request a device context (aka dc), then a drawing surface, then we draw. The device context part is where [WARP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx) comes in. A dc is usually fronting a hardware device - but in my project I am targeting a service on a server where it is unlikely that there will be a graphics processor, and maybe not even a video card. If it is a virtual server then the video processor may be shared etc. So I don't want to be tied to a 'physical' hardware device. Enter WARP ([good time to view the link for full context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx)), which is an entirely software realisation of a dc - no hardware dependency. Sweet. Here is an extract from the linked page:

> **Enabling Rendering When Direct3D 10 Hardware is Not Available**
>
> WARP allows fast rendering in a variety of situations where hardware
>   implementations are unavailable, including:
>
> When the user does not have any Direct3D-capable hardware When an application runs as a service or in a server environment
>
> When a video card is not installed
>
> When a video driver is not available, or is not working correctly
>
> When a video card is out of memory, hangs, or would take too many system resources to initialize

Comment: It definitely will.

Comment: IMHO using directx on a server, is somewhat overkill (limited video memory resources). I would go with GDI+

Comment: GDI+ will work on a server. There might be caveats to using it in a service however (unrelated to the machines role as a server).

Comment: If you want to go for directx, you should create a separate server with a queue.

Comment: "GDI is 32-bit"... Ask your colleagues whether 64-bit Windows can work without GDI. If they say "yes", don't listen their suggestions in future - they are beginners in software development. BTW, I think GDI will be enough for your needs, without GDI+.

Comment: Recommending DirectX on a server itself seems odd as it seems to have the curious property of coupling the performance of your server to the quality of its graphics card - normally not something you think about for a device that pretty much runs headless.

Comment: @i486 - I have looked at GDI (not plus) and find that it relies on unmanaged code which puts me off a bit.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - A separate server with a queue is the possible long-term architecture. Regardless though, we have to select the tech to write the code that processes the queue.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat insofar as you're not running on server core, or any of the reduced versions you can use GDI. However I would consider using Direct2D on D3D11 using WARP. This decouples your care about the server graphics (usually garbage) and takes advantage of any SIMD options within the CPU itself.

Comment: @ChrisBecke I'd use WARP as my rasterizer in this case to take advantage of SIMD which won't be an option with GDI. Also you can produce nicer images with Direct2D. Actually it [looks like they can bypass GDI or DirectX all together](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719658(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: gdiplus is really a c++ wrapper with extra goodies that wraps GDI. There is a .NET version that looks very similar, but I don't know if wraps or reimplements the native version (or if its a managed c++ build of the same code).

Comment: I use DirectX (SharpDx) on a web sever for the sole reason that GDI+ kerns text in a bad way. Everyhing else is done with GDI+, but I had to use DirectX to get better text rendering!

Comment: @DanByström - we are stumbling a bit getting traction with SharpDX, I have asked another question -
 can you contribute ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305472/sharpdx-warp-minimal-code-to-get-a-drawable-surface

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would probably try to go with SkiaSharp (https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) to abstract a bit from the platform/API details

Comment: Thanks - platform/API details are not specifically an issue since we target one platform and are happy dealing with an API. But SkiaSharp looks like a potential - at least there is activity on the project so it seems to be live.

Comment: ...so you're saying that SkiaSharp would be a better choice than SharpDx...?

Comment: I meant that Direct2D/DirectWrite is a bit more low level than SkiaSharp that is hiding many details of these low level APIs. You can have a look at this sample https://gist.github.com/xoofx/a9d08a37c43f692e65df80a1888c488b  the equivalent for Direct2D/DirectWrite will require quite a bit more work

Comment: Thanks @xoofx - that link is illuminating and I get your point that SkiaSharp is more succinct than SharpDX. The guys are currently feeling their way through SharpDX setting up devices, 3d and 2d contexts etc and there seems to be a lot to know before anything productive gets done. However, that may all be tucked away in an init function that we never look at again. Could you suggest any tutorials or how-to's for SkiaSharp? (Looked at your github and see only that one).

Comment: Apart small dive into the API like https://skia.org/user/api/skpaint don't know any. SkiaSharp should be pretty close to the native API.