# SharpDX WARP - minimal code to get a drawable surface

Tags: c#, sharpdx, warp

I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284835/iis-service-based-generation-of-web-images-gdi-gdi-or-direct2d) about generating high quality graphics in a service on Windows Server and SharpDX looks like a reasonable possibility. However I am finding it difficult to find current how-to style documentation. I am specifically interested in the WARP device context.

My use-case is for generation of png format images, and steps of interest are initialisation, loading existing images, drawing graphics and text on them, a resizing / scaling, and saving to png format. I mention this as a large part of the potential use cases for SharpDX are game-related and focus on buffer chains and rendering to forms, which I do not need to do.

This is question 1 then - what is the minimal C# code required to create a drawable 2D surface using WARP in SharpDx in preparation for the above use case.

Other code I have found via Google is either game-focussed, not using WARP, or is simply too complex as it covers more basis.

Comment: (continued from other question) if you drop me a note a danXdanbystromXse you can have some live working code to get you an idea. I rather not post it here because it is not beautiful reading. :-$

Comment: Thanks @DanByström - email sent a little while ago.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution for this? I have exactly the same use case (server image generation) and would love to know.